# Why no error is thrown in compilation?

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int i = 0;
  int *a;
  do
    {
      scanf("%d",&a[i]);
      i++;
    }
  while (a[i-1]!=-1);
}
```

This code reads numbers until `-1` is encountered. The pointer `a` is not initialized but the code still compiles & runs without any error. Why? Can this be a way to initialize an array without declaring its size?

Comment: Why do you expect a *compile-time* error?

Comment: The code will surely die. It's *undefined behavior* which means *anything* could happen, practically.

Comment: C gives you the noose and the hangman. be careful

Comment: since you did not assign any value to `*a` garabage is stored there, and that garbage has a memory address and can be used as an array

Comment: I dont see any array in your code. What are you taking about?

Comment: @iBug: Because the fact that `a` is used without being initialized is plainly visible to the compiler, and the compiler ought to warn about using uninitialized objects by default.

Comment: @EricPostpischil *by default*? No. Not unless I explicitly supply `-Wunintialized` (or `-Wall` or so).

Comment: @iBug: I wrote “ought to,” not “does.” I am fully aware the GCC default options are deficient. But why would a novice assume that a tool is crippled by default? It is natural to assume that a tool would be configured to do a good job by default. You asked why OP would expect a compile-time error. This answers your question.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: There is no requirement the compiler has to warn. Expecially a novice should learn about the tools he uses and the gcc documentation is well comprehensible. The code itself is simple enough to understand it does not make sense, even for a beginner. But that happens if one does not get a good book, but tries to learn C by trial and error and obscure online "tutorials" or youtube videos.

Comment: _sigh_ Something to always keep in mind: **The reason why pointers are called "pointer", not "array" (and vice-versa) is a pointer is not an array, nor is an array a pointer**

Comment: @Olaf: The **C standard** does not require a warning. **High quality** requires a warning. **A good tool does a good job.** The C standard is not the sole criterion of how a compiler behaves. The default behavior **should** (not “is required by the C standard”) be to do a good job. In any case, your question has been answered. People would expect a warning because it is the job of the compiler (not required by the standard, but required by expectations of quality) to warn about uninitialized objects when the lack of initialization is readily visible to the compiler.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Please provide a reference to the standard defining the term "high quality". About the good tool: Even a good tool is only as good as the person using it. If you don't read the manual of a modern car, you cannot complain you don't utilize all it's features. The same applies of course for the most complicated tool mankind developed: computers and software, of course. "should" is very subjective and your personal opinion. You can't make any halfway complex system fool-proof.

Comment: @Olaf: Yes, if you do not read the manual of a modern car, you can complain. I drive rental cars with some frequency, and it is not feasible to spend an hour reading the manual in the parking garage before moving the vehicle. We expect standardized controls and useful features. The market for cars that just barely meet street-legal requirements and have no other features is minimal. I do not know if GCC or other compilers have formal documents about quality, but…

Comment: … it is perfectly clear that a compiler that warns by default about something that is clearly a problem (is not correct code in any circumstance) is better than a compiler that does not. It is clear that a compiler that produces faster code or produces code faster is better than a compiler that does neither, all else being equal. There can be value judgements about situations where there are trade-offs, such as a warning about something that is usually wrong but may be needed in some circumstances. In the absence of such a trade-off, there is no question that warning is better than not.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: And of course you did never take driving school where you learned those standard controls and the trafic rules in your country. And you don check how the wipers work, if the car is benzine or diesel or electric, etc. Sorry to say, but those are very lame excuses.

Comment: @Olaf: You have some misguided notion that a compiler ought to be judged solely by formal specifications. Nonsense. These are tools made for humans. Tools should serve their users, and they should serve them well. That is an important quality, one with many benefits.

Comment: @Olaf: The car was your analogy. Driving school covers only the basics. I expect cars to have more features than the basics. Hence, your analogy fails to support your point. People expect good cars to do more than the basics, and they want good cars. People expect televisions and operating systems to do more than the basics. People expect food to do more than just provide essential nutrition. People expect clothing to do more than just protect from the environment. Otherwise, they judge them as garbage. Asserting nothing should be expected of a tool more than the absolute minimum is absurd.

Comment: @Olaf: In any case, even if you do expect nothing of a tool other than it perform in the most minimal way it can without being subject to lawsuit, your question has been answered. Other people have higher expectations. So now you know why a person would expect more from the compiler. Even if your expectations are absurdly low, you cannot deny that other people expect more. So you no longer need to question why somebody expects a warning from the compiler. Your question is answered.

Comment: @EricPostpischil "Tools should serve their users, and they should serve them well. " - I fully agree. That#s why I enable (allmost) all warning messages when I use the compiler and appreciate gcc has so powerful checking options. You completely missed the point.

Comment: @Olaf: Since you believe tools should serve their users, tell us what purpose is served by not having the default options be as useful as they can be? When there is no downside to providing a warning, why is it not provided? I get your point that the compiler is the way it is, and a professional must learn how to use it. But that is not relevant to what a novice expects. A novice does not know how the compiler works, and their expectation is that good tools are easy to use and serve them well…

Comment: … Even if you educate this one questioner, that will do nothing to educate the many millions more to follow. Novice after novice will expect the tool to do a better job. You cannot improve that by changing humans; we cannot change their DNA in any substantial way. You can improve that by improving the tool. Any one human can be educated over time to use a complex tool, but educating each human individually is wasteful compared to improving a tool once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can this be a way to initialize an array without declaring its size?

No.

All `int *a;` does, if *defining* a **pointer** to `int`, which, as not being initialised, points somewhere, "nowhere", to "invalid" memory.

Any invocation of the `[]`-operator on `a`, without beforehand having made `a` point to any valid memory (as for example the OP's your code does) invokes undefined behaviour, anything may happen from then on, from crash to seemingly working.

---

Assuming that by "*declare*" you in fact mean "define" the only way to define an array with "unknown" size is by providing an initaliser (with well known size) at definition of the array, like so:

```
int arr[] = {-1, 0, 42}; /* Defines arr to be an array of three ints. */
```

Right after the creation/initialisation `arr` *has* a well know size of three  `int`.

Please note that the `=` sign above is not the same as the assignment operator `=`. The following code will not compile:

```
int arr[]; 
arr = {-1, 0, 42}; /* Invalid, as an array may not be assigned. */
```

---

To make GCC be more chatty about what all might be suspicious in the code it is fed pass the following options when compiling:

```
-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wconversion
```

Answer (score 8):

**GCC doesn't warn of uninitialized values by default.**

You need the `-Wuninitialized` option:

```
gcc -Wuninitialized your_file.c
```

You should probably use the `-Wall` option instead to enable this warning alongside lots of other useful warnings.

More information on warning options [**here**](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html)